# nginx server can't read pem key provided by Ionos

Tags: ssl, nginx

```
    -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
 contents
    -----END CERTIFICATE-----
    
    -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
contents
    -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

but I still get the following error in the logs when i restart the service

```
2023/09/14 19:50:33 [emerg] 2655#2655: cannot load certificate key "/home/alfred/AccentaG4/key.pem": PEM_read_bio_PrivateKey() failed (SSL: error:2807106B:UI routines:UI_process:processing error:while reading strings error:0906406D:PEM routines:PEM_def_callback:problems getting password error:0906A068:PEM routines:PEM_do_header:bad password read)
```

Sorry I am new to nginx and ssl setup in general. So if there's anything else I need to post just ask.

```
root      2756  0.0  0.4  49792  2040 ?        Ss   20:04   0:00 nginx: master process /usr/sbin/nginx -g daemon on; master_process on;
www-data  2757  0.0  0.6  49928  2968 ?        S    20:04   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

So I said www-data owns the certificate and the private key but I still get the same error. I didn't try root because I thought root has permission to everything anyway.

so here's the permissions for the key file

```
-rw------- 1 www-data root 1766 Sep 14 20:07 /etc/ssl/private/key.pem
```

The following is what I see when i open my key file. I am guessing my key file is encrypted lol

```
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,string of letters and numbers
```

So the certificate came with the domain free of charge for a year.
Next year I'll use lets encrypt.
When I login to the control panel for my domain I only see the following:

[image]

Sorry I am confused here. I understand it's encrypted and I need a password.
Is what I need here in a different format or do I need to ask my provider for the password?

Comment: Do user which start nginx have file permission to read in your directory and specificly `/home/alfred/AccentaG4/key.pem`?

Comment: where do ppl usually put the certificates? I put in the home directory for alfred because it used to be attached to the web application itself. I was told the usual way to do it is to just attach it to the reverse proxy

Comment: If you are using encrypted private keys you need to provide the password - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33084347/pass-cert-password-to-nginx-with-https-site-during-restart

Comment: Actually you can put them anywhere. But the user (which run nginx) need to have read rights over the file. The usual place is somewhere in `/etc` under the nginx config

Comment: hi updated my post

Comment: Check and try also the link from Steffen

Comment: Hi i have updated my post with what I see when I login to the control panel for my domain. I don't see a password. Surely they will get it me otherwise how am i supposed to use my certificate?

Comment: thanks alot I found I managed to mix up the certificate I generated with the one provided by my domain registrar. Their certificate and key file just worked.